# Why does my image turn white before fading away when interpolating its alpha from 1 to 0?

Tags: javascript, colors, shader, webgl, blending

I'm developing a program that utilizes WebGL and I have a function that draws images. The fragment shader looks like this:

```
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec4 u_tint;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord) * u_tint;
}
```

I then have another function that draws the image every frame with the alpha component of the tint interpolating from `1.0` to `0.0`. That is, the progression might look something like this:

```
Frame 0: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 1.0 ]
Frame 1: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 0.9 ]
Frame 2: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 0.8 ]
Frame 3: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 0.7 ]
Frame 4: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 0.6 ]
Frame 5: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 0.5 ]
Frame 6: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 0.4 ]
Frame 7: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 0.3 ]
Frame 8: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 0.2 ]
Frame 9: Tint =  [ 1, 1, 1, 0.1 ]
Frame 10: Tint = [ 1, 1, 1, 0.0 ]
```

The confusing thing is that, for whatever reason, the image starts off looking normal, fades to almost a pure white, and then finally fades out. The progression looks something like this:

[image]

Notice how while the image does fade into the background, it first gets very bright before doing so. It appears to be at maximum brightness when the alpha is around `0.5`.

Is there any way to avoid the image getting brighter as it fades into the background? My intuition was that fading the alpha component from `1.0` to `0.0` would slowly blend the image into the same color as the background, but for whatever reason it seems to also increase the brightness of the image first.

**Edit:** I've made some progress in understanding the problem. It appears that if I change the background color for the website (as in, in CSS) from the default (white) to black, then it gets rid of the white tint and makes it look a lot better. But I guess my question is, why is changing the alpha value making it fade into the background of the website and not the background of the frame buffer? And can this be fixed?

Comment: Is premultiplied alpha enabled? If so `vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord) * u_tint;` `gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 1.0) * color.a;`

Comment: Those two lines of code didn't seem to have an effect, in that it looks as if there was no change from what is currently occurring.

Comment: blend mode and depth test enableded?

Comment: @Denis Sorry for the late reply I was sleeping. Yeah, blending is enabled. I didn't think I would need depth test but I just tried enabling it and the same behavior is occurring (that is, no change).

Comment: try disabling premultiplied alpha and/or alpha in the [context creation paramters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#parameters).